# Android Preference value behaving strangely

Tags: android

I'm using a preference screen in a non-standard way, to set values for a class called Reminder. When I open the EditReminder activity with an existing reminder, it pulls in the appropriate reminder from an intent, and then initializes the preference screen like so:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("temp_name",reminder.getName());
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), reminder.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    editor.putString("temp_description",reminder.getDescription());
    editor.putString("temp_time",timeFormat.format(reminder.getDate().getTime()));
    editor.putString("temp_date",dateFormat.format(reminder.getDate().getTime()));
    editor.apply();

    name.setSummary(reminder.getName());
    description.setSummary(reminder.getDescription());
    time.setSummary(timeFormat.format(reminder.getDate().getTime()));
    date.setSummary(dateFormat.format(reminder.getDate().getTime()));
```

When I first open the app and attempt to edit an existing reminder, this works flawlessly. However, from then on, the summaries will be correctly set to the correct values, and if I save immediately the correct values get saved, so the code appears to be working. Except that if I tap a preference, the pre-filled value is for the previous reminder.

So if I open Reminder1 and tap name, it prefills the edittext dialog with "Reminder1"

Then if I open Reminder2 and tap name, it prefills the edittext dialog with "Reminder1"

Then if I open Reminder3 and tap name, it prefills the edittext dialog with "Reminder2"

The toast is there for value testing, since my logcat lags by about 8 minutes, but that's another question. The toast displays the correct value. Also, as I mentioned, the summaries are set to the correct value, and if I save without making any changes, it saves the correct values. I'm baffled.

Per request, here is the code where I save the values set by the user:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    reminder.setName(sharedPreferences.getString("temp_name",""));
    reminder.setDescription(sharedPreferences.getString("temp_description", ""));
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm aa"+"EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy");
    try {
        date.setTime(timeFormat.parse(sharedPreferences.getString("temp_time", "") + sharedPreferences.getString("temp_date", "")));
    }
    catch (ParseException e){
        Log.e("Minder","Parse Error");
    }

    long time = date.getTimeInMillis();                             //Drop seconds
    time = time/60000;                                              //
    time = time*60000;                                              //
    date.setTimeInMillis(time);                                     //
    reminder.setDate(date);                                         //Store reminder date + time
    ReminderDBHelper dbHelper = ReminderDBHelper.getInstance(this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.openDatabase();
    reminder.setId( (int) Reminder.saveReminder(database,reminder));//Save reminder to database
```

And the relevant xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<EditTextPreference android:title="Name"
    android:key="temp_name"
    android:summary="@string/name_summary"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:singleLine="true"/>

<EditTextPreference android:title="Description"
    android:key="temp_description"
    android:summary="@string/description_summary"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"/>

<us.bridgeses.Minder.util.TimePreference android:title="Time"
    android:key="temp_time"
    android:inputType="time"/>

<us.bridgeses.Minder.util.DatePreference android:title="Date"
    android:key="temp_date"
    android:inputType="date"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: We need to see more code. Show the UI code where you fill the values based on preferences.

Comment: You need to learn how to use the Eclipse or Android Studio debugger.

Comment: I'm working on it. But as an answer to my question that is a singularly unhelpful comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

I had a poke through the source code for `EditTextPreference` and realized it initialized its internal storage variable as soon as it was initialized and not (as I had for some reason assumed) when the preference was actually tapped.

I was doing the above assignments *after* calling `addPreferencesFromResource`, which meant the preferences were intializing their values before the assignments were being called. I moved that call to after the variable assignments and it worked fine.

I had initially only assigned the summaries, which I do by pulling the preferences from the xml. That had to be done after `addPreferencesFromResource` or there would be no xml to pull from. The value assignments, however, are done directly via `SharedPreferences.Editor` and don't need the xml to be associated first.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good except for one line.

I never use apply() i always use commit()

According to the doco:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are completed as well as the commit itself.

I think without writing to persistent storage immediately, the next time you use preferences screen, you will get persistent data (or defaults)

Comment: I had the same thought, except for two things:
1) I tried commit. It was actually the first thing I thought to try.
2) Android Studio gives a warning when you use commit and tells you to use apply instead

Comment: One idea comes to mind. Is your minimum sdk less than 16? There were compatibility issues and a different shared preference object must be used.

Comment: It was lower than 16. Raising it to 16 or above had no effect.